# i want to get the mail id in dropbox,how can i retrieve the from dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox

//i want to get the mail id  from  dropbox,how can i retrieve the mails and username from dropbox.is their any way to get the username and mailid,please help me how can i retrieve the mail id.i am using coreapi to implement this one please help me how can i get the those deatils.

```
public class PrefernceDropBox extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "DBRoulette";
    public ProgressDialog dialog;
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Your app-specific settings. //
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Replace this with your app key and secret assigned by Dropbox.
    // Note that this is a really insecure way to do this, and you shouldn't
    // ship code which contains your key & secret in such an obvious way.
    // Obfuscation is good.
    final static private String APP_KEY = "XXXX";
    final static private String APP_SECRET = "XXXXX";

    // If you'd like to change the access type to the full Dropbox instead of
    // an app folder, change this value.
    final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;

    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // End app-specific settings. //
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // You don't need to change these, leave them alone.
    final static private String ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    final static private String ACCESS_KEY_NAME = "ACCESS_KEY";
    final static private String ACCESS_SECRET_NAME = "ACCESS_SECRET";

    DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mApi;

    private boolean mLoggedIn;

    // Android widgets
    private Button mSubmit, mDownload;
    private LinearLayout mDisplay;
    private Button mPhoto;
    private Button mRoulette;

    private ImageView mImage;

    private final String PHOTO_DIR = "/Photos/";

    final static private int NEW_PICTURE = 1;
    private String mCameraFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(PrefernceDropBox.this);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCameraFileName = savedInstanceState.getString("mCameraFileName");
        }

        // We create a new AuthSession so that we can use the Dropbox API.
        AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
        mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

        // Basic Android widgets
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        checkAppKeySetup();

        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.auth_button);

        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // This logs you out if you're logged in, or vice versa
                if (mLoggedIn) {
                    logOut();
                } else {
                    // Start the remote authentication
                    mApi.getSession()
                            .startAuthentication(PrefernceDropBox.this);
                }
            }
        });

        // Display the proper UI state if logged in or not
        setLoggedIn(mApi.getSession().isLinked());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("mCameraFileName", mCameraFileName);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AndroidAuthSession session = mApi.getSession();

        // The next part must be inserted in the onResume() method of the
        // activity from which session.startAuthentication() was called, so
        // that Dropbox authentication completes properly.
        if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // Mandatory call to complete the auth
                session.finishAuthentication();

                // Store it locally in our app for later use
                TokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
                storeKeys(tokens.key, tokens.secret);
                setLoggedIn(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                showToast("Couldn't authenticate with Dropbox:"
                        + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.i(TAG, "Error authenticating", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void logOut() {
        // Remove credentials from the session
        mApi.getSession().unlink();

        // Clear our stored keys
        clearKeys();
        // Change UI state to display logged out version
        setLoggedIn(false);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience function to change UI state based on being logged in
     */
    private void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        mLoggedIn = loggedIn;
        if (loggedIn) {
            mSubmit.setText("signout from Dropbox");
            // mDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mSubmit.setText("Sign into Dropbox");
            // mDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // mImage.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    }

    private void checkAppKeySetup() {
        // Check to make sure that we have a valid app key
        if (APP_KEY.startsWith("CHANGE") || APP_SECRET.startsWith("CHANGE")) {
            showToast("You must apply for an app key and secret from developers.dropbox.com, and add them to the DBRoulette ap before trying it.");
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Check if the app has set up its manifest properly.
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String scheme = "db-" + APP_KEY;
        String uri = scheme + "://" + AuthActivity.AUTH_VERSION + "/test";
        testIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        if (0 == pm.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, 0).size()) {
            showToast("URL scheme in your app's "
                    + "manifest is not set up correctly. You should have a "
                    + "com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity with the "
                    + "scheme: " + scheme);
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }

    /**
     * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a
     * local store, rather than storing user name & password, and
     * re-authenticating each time (which is not to be done, ever).
     * 
     * @return Array of [access_key, access_secret], or null if none stored
     */
    private String[] getKeys() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
        String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
        if (key != null && secret != null) {
            String[] ret = new String[2];
            ret[0] = key;
            ret[1] = secret;
            return ret;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a
     * local store, rather than storing user name & password, and
     * re-authenticating each time (which is not to be done, ever).
     */
    private void storeKeys(String key, String secret) {
        // Save the access key for later
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, key);
        edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, secret);
        edit.commit();
    }

    private void clearKeys() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.commit();
    }

    private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
        AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session;

        String[] stored = getKeys();
        if (stored != null) {
            AccessTokenPair accessToken = new AccessTokenPair(stored[0],
                    stored[1]);
            session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE,
                    accessToken);
        } else {
            session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE);
        }

        return session;
    }
}
```